# How to NOT save username and password in the loginButtons template of Meteor?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

I'm using the loginButtons template in Meteor to build a project. The login buttons show up and work well but every time I log out and try to log in again the username and password from the previous user are kept in the input boxes. How can I turn this off?

Answer (score 1):

This is from the web browser, to disable it you can set autocomplete false on forms.
You can do something like this https://gist.github.com/runspired/b9fdf1fa74fc9fb4554418dea35718fe

However this is an desired feat of the browser and large sites have this in case you select "save password".

You can clear your browser site history to avoid seeing previous user data and then don't select save password..

Comment: But I'm using the Blaze template and I can't change the attributes of the input elements from outside the template.